# How to load webview from another viewcontroller?

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview

I created two views as `ViewController` and `RadarViewController`. `RadarViewController` just have a `UIWebView`. I'm trying to load webpage from `ViewController`. I'm using a `viewDidLoad()` code in `RadarViewController` it executes the code, but I cannot see any loaded webpages. What is wrong?

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let url = NSURL(string: "http://www.sourcefreeze.com")
    let requestObj = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)
    webPage.loadRequest(requestObj)
}
```

Comment: "It doesn't work" is never a sufficient explanation for your problem.

Comment: how do you make the transition from `ViewController` to `RadarViewController`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to move the code to `viewWillAppear` function because in `viewDidLoad` the `UIViews` will not be ready yet.

Comment: unfortunately same:( Am I need to use viewWillAppear in ViewController class?

Comment: what is exactly happening?

Comment: Luckily, it roots in internet speed. I noticed just now. Thanks @Firas

Comment: try to conform  the `UIWebViewDelegate` protocol and then check inside the `webViewDidStartLoad` what's happen

Comment: and check didFailLoadWithError function.